# Set Powershell as login shell in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, powershell

In Ubuntu 19.04 `sudo apt install powershell` fails with

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 powershell : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
              Depends: libicu60 but it is not installable
```

Installing it with `snap install powershell --classic` works, but then it doesn't show up in `/etc/shells` so `chsh` doesn't work.

How to fix this?

Comment: `powershell` isn't in official repository. Are you using some PPA?

Comment: I followed [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6#ubuntu-1804)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### To install Powershell using Snap

- Run

  ```
  sudo snap install powershell --classic
  ```

#### To install Powershell using APT

Microsoft updated their [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6) on 08/06/2018 in which they described steps for 18.04. Their repositories for Powershell are neither updated for 18.10 nor for 19.04.

In default repository of 19.04, libssl is now at version 1.1.1 and libcu is now at version 63. So, in order to use bionic's package, bionic's dependencies need to be used.

- Install dependencies using dpkg:

  ```
  wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
  ```
- Add Microsoft's repository information:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
  ```

  Add the content below and save that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd>.

  ```
  deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic main
  ```
- Update and install Powershell

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install powershell
  ```

#### To set Powershell as default shell:

- Check if the path of Powershell is in ***/etc/shells***. If not, add that. For Snap installation it is ***/snap/bin/pwsh*** and for packages installed via APT, it is ***/usr/bin/pwsh***.
- Run `chsh` and enter password.
- Enter the path of Powershell.
- Re-login or reboot.

Comment: Something I may have missed: can you just add a line in `etc/shells`? I thought the line was not there for some incompatibility with the installation via snap.

Comment: @rzippo Yes. That is like a regular text file. You need to have sudo privileges to edit that.

Comment: When trying this on Ubuntu 20, `/snap/bin/pwsh` didn't work for me - had to specify `/snap/powershell/current/opt/powershell/pwsh` instead.